# How to rig/animate a charater in swift scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, scenekit

I would like to place a 3d character in a scene and change its pose based on various 3d transforms that I collected from an AR session. Because the transforms are collected in the app, using an external app like blender for the animations won't work because I need the animations to be produced directly after the transforms are collected.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to go about doing this. I've researched scnSkinner but there is very little documentation for it. I believe I have to import a .dae rigged character into the scene, but I'm not entirely sure how to manipulate the joints. Any resources or suggestions are much appreciated!!!

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
        var upperArm: SCNNode?        
        arScene.scene = SCNScene(named: "Christie.dae")!
        upperArm = arScene.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "upperarm_R", recursively: true)!
        upperArm?.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -1)
```

but this seems to just cause the model to be deformed as opposed to moving the actual joint.

Comment: I highly recommend you to create separate animation files in an external app like Blender (or give Mixamo a try). You can use SCNAnimation Player to load then the animation files and apply them to your rigged character. Manipulating each part of the skelton in code will drive you crazy at some point.

Comment: @ZAY Thanks for the recommendation! Unfortunately I need to do the animation in the app because the joint transforms that I would like to supply to the character are collected in an Ar session while the app is in use, and therefore can't be pre made in an external app.

Comment: Try my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76632656/848485. It should give a good starting point for how to go about this.