# How to set a bone/joint position of SCNSkinner object using SCNIKConstraint?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to rig a robot model (in this case, it's Apple's robot model) using a set of keypoint data that I have. At this moment I'm trying to move all of the arm joints using `SCNIKConstraint`. I found a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76632656/8279130) that explains how to achieve this but unfortunately it doesn't work when I tried it. Here's what I did:

1. Loading the robot model

   ```
   private func loadBipedRobotModel() {
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "biped_robot", withExtension: "usdz")!

        guard let referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: modelURL) else { return }
        referenceNode.load()

        guard let acePLYNode = referenceNode.childNode(withName: "ace_PLY", recursively: true) else { return }
        guard let skinner = acePLYNode.skinner else { return }

        referenceNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
        referenceNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(3, 3, 3)
        scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(referenceNode)

        bipedRobotModelNode = referenceNode
        bipedRobotModelSkinner = skinner
    }
   ```
2. Setting up the Inverse Kinematics constraint

   ```
   func setBipedRightArmInverseKinematicsConstraints() {
    guard
        let rightShoulderJoint = bipedRobotModelSkinner.bones.first(where: { $0.name == BipedRobotJointNames.rightShoulder1.rawValue }),
        let rightHandJoint = bipedRobotModelSkinner.bones.first(where: { $0.name == BipedRobotJointNames.rightHand.rawValue })
    else { return }

    bipedRobotRightArmIKConstraint = SCNIKConstraint(chainRootNode: rightShoulderJoint)
    rightHandJoint.constraints = [bipedRobotRightArmIKConstraint]
   }
   ```
3. Set the new position

   ```
   guard let rightHandTargetPosition = currentKeypoint.getKeypoint(type: .rightHand)?.getConvertedPosition(relativeTo: CGFloat(studioSize)) else { return }
   bipedRobotRightArmIKConstraint.targetPosition = rightHandTargetPosition
   ```

Unfortunately the arms doesn't move at all and the robot is still just T-posing. Is there any way to solve this? Am I missing something in my implementation. Thanks.